# mongodb - exclude a specific field from results array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Below is partnership collection which has users 1 and 2 who participated. One of the users is the current logged in user available as `req.user._id` and I am listing the user's partners.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6381697ddddbdb42b4682fb7"
    },
    "users": [{
        "$oid": "user_one_id"
    }, {
        "$oid": "user_two_id"
    }],
}
```

I am getting the fields of the user who is partner from PartnerModel (excluding the req.user._id). Assuming in this case, `req.user._id` is `user_one_id`

```js
let partners =
  await userPartnerModel.find({
    users: { $in: [req.user._id] }
  }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate({ 
      path: 'users', 
      select: 'profilePic firstName', 
      model: userModel 
    })

res.status(200).json(partners)
```

The issue is that partners result also includes the req.user.

The result I am getting now is:

```
  {
      "users":[
         {
            "firstName":"User One",
            "profilePic":"https://image.jpg",
            "_id":"63729a9a73f736476cbdd0cc"
         },
         {
            "firstName":"User Two",
            "profilePic":"https://image2.jpg",
            "_id":"63728ae473f736476cbdd0be"
         }
```

But the results should not include `req.user._id` which is "User One"

Comment: Use https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use the `select` function to allow only the field you want. By default the _id field is allowed you can disallow it by adding `-id`. For your case you can use this query:

```js
let partners =
  await userPartnerModel.find({
    users: { $in: [req.user._id] }
  }).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate({ 
      path: 'users', 
      select: 'profilePic firstName -_id', 
      model: userModel 
    })
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I am not just trying to exclude id. I am trying to exclude the entire `user one` because that user is the same as `req.user._id` (current logged in user)